# How to add null in text input if user does not enter any address

Tags: ethereum, solidity, remix, tron, tronbox

```
    function deposit(address payable referrer) public payable whenNotPaused
    {  
    
    }
```

In my case I need insert address, otherway I will get:
"{"reason":"invalid address","code":"INVALID_ARGUMENT","arg":"","coderType":"address","value":""}"

Is there any way if user not enter any text, can add my own text in Solidity?

This box is marked as required, but I want as not required.

I used shasta.tronscan.org .

In my JS no problem, but if user use directly then need to use from code Solidity.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm trying to understand your question.
 Are you want to use `default parameters`?

Well, Solidity does not support default parameters, but it is on their roadmap (see https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/232). To work around this, just use `function overloading`:

```
function deposit() public payable whenNotPaused{  
    address referrer = 0x.....   // use your default parameter.
    //Your code

  }

function deposit(address payable referrer) public payable whenNotPaused {  
    // Your Code
    }
```